# Excel formula function to remove spaces between characters

Tags: excel

In Excel sheet i did a form that customer need to fill out, i have a cell that the customer need to enter his Email Address, I need to data validate the cell as much i can and am nearly success this is what i did:

```
' this formula is for email structuring
=ISNUMBER(MATCH("*@*.???",A5,0))

' this formula to check if there is spaces at start and the end
=IF(LEN(A5)>LEN(TRIM(A5)),FALSE,TRUE)
```

But if i right for example (admin@ad min.com) the second formula will not detect the space between the email address, any clue?

Comment: `=SUBSTITUTE(A5," ","")` will take care of *all* spaces in the cell

Comment: Thanks never thought about it

Comment: Trim removes leading and trailing spaces as well as converting multiple interim spaces into single interim spaces (e.g. `a   b` becomes `a b`) but is not the correct function to completely remove all spaces.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use SUBSTITUTE()

```
=IF(LEN(A5)>LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A5," ","")),FALSE,TRUE)
```

Answer (score 3):

How about:

```
=IF(LEN(A5)>LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A5," ","")),FALSE,TRUE)
```

based on Jeeped's comment:

```
 =A5=SUBSTITUTE(A5," ","")
```

Comment: or more simply as `=LEN(A5)=LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A5," ",""))`

Comment: @Jeeped  ***OUCH!!***  or even `=A5=SUBSTITUTE(A5," ","")`

Answer (score 0):

You can use VBA to perform validation using regular expressions - after removing any spaces.

## Option 1

#### Returning a Boolean True/False

```vb
Public Function validateEmail(strEmail As String) As Boolean

    ' Remove spaces
    strEmail = Replace(strEmail, " ", "")

    ' Validate email using regular expressions
    With CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
        .ignorecase = True
        .Pattern = "^[-.\w]+@[-.\w]+\.\w{2,5}$"
        If .test(strEmail) Then validateEmail = True
    End With

End Function
```

This can be used as a normal worksheet function such as:

```
=validateEmail("yourEmail@test.com")
```

```
=validateEmail($A1)
```

Can also be used in VBA as well

```vb
debug.print validateEmail("yourEmail@test.com")
```

## Option 2

#### Returning the email itself, or return False

If you would prefer that it returns the validated email instead of a Boolean (true/False), then you can do something like:

```vb
Public Function validateEmail(strEmail As String) As Variant

    ' Remove spaces
    strEmail = Replace(strEmail, " ", "")

    ' Validate email using regular expressions
    With CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
        .ignorecase = True
        .Pattern = "^[-.\w]+@[-.\w]+\.\w{2,5}$"
        If .test(strEmail) Then
            validateEmail = strEmail
        Else
            validateEmail = False
        End If
    End With

End Function
```

So, using in a worksheet function for example, using `=validateEmail("yourEmail @ test.com")` will return the string: **yourEmail@test.com**. However, if the email is invalid such as `validateEmail("yourEmailtest.com")` then it will return **False**.

---

*Why use Regular Expressions?* Checking for a simple `@` in the string to validate an email is only a minimal workaround. A string input such as `()#&&*^$@893---------6584.ido` would match your `=ISNUMBER(MATCH("*@*.???",A5,0))` formula, yet that is obviously not a valid email. Obviously there is no way to 100% validate an email - however, this does a decent job at at the very least ensuring the email *could be* valid.